# ngbdropdownMenu with ngfor - fix the top position

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, ng-bootstrap

I try to fix the top of the two ngbdropdownMenu to open them at the same top position.

https://angular-k6zs3w.stackblitz.io

I changed to css but it doesn't work, is there anyone who has already done it?

Comment: the effect which you want, what should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the boostrap class in your `style.css`:

```
.dropdown-menu.show {
   transform:translate(173.156px, 0px) !important;
}
```

But it's not very nice.

Comment: Edited, that was .dropdown-menu.show and not .dropdown-menu .show